# SQL em dados propagados

Tags: sql, oracle

Preciso acertar o SQL abaixo para o banco de dados `Oracle`.

A ideia é recuperar o código da tabela `Produto`  associado ao código da tabela `Matriz`.

Nesssa estrutura, a `Matriz` tem relação com pelo menos uma `Filial` e esta contém o link para o `Produto`. Mas uma `Filial` pode ter uma `Filial`, que pode ter uma `Filial`, etc.

Ou seja, para alcançar os códigos relacionados nas tabelas `Produto` e `Matriz`, preciso de uma retro propagação da informação existente na tabela relacional `Filial`, que resolvi com o `START WITH` e `CONNECT BY PRIOR`.

Tive sucesso testando o sub-select abaixo separado com um registro de exemplo. Mas não consigo extrair todos os registros.

Tentei fazer desta forma (espero que não esteja confuso), mas o subselect não enxerga a tabela externa.

```
select produto.nome, produto.qtde, tabelaAux.codigo from produto
  left join (select * from
    (select matriz.codigo as codMatriz, matriz.codFilial as codFilial
    from matriz
    left join filial on filial.codC = matriz.codigo
    start with filial.codA = produto.codigo          --falha aqui
    connect by prior filial.codigoPai = filial.codigo)
  where codMatriz is not null)
  tabelaAUX on tabelaAUX.codFilial = produto.codFilial;
```

Comment: Recomendo você utilizar o site http://sqlfiddle.com, colocar a estrutura base com alguns dados, que possamos te ajudar

Comment: Não entendi pois em geral CONNECT BY é usado para SQL´S recursivos , um exemplo clássico é o funcionario (matricula,nome,matricula_do_superior)   https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm

Answer (score 1):

Já tentou assim?

```
SELECT PRODUTO.NOME,
PRODUTO.QTDE,
TABELAAUX.CODIGO,
TABELAAUX.NOME_MATRIZ,
TABELAAUX.NOME_FILIAL
FROM PRODUTO
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT MATRIZ.CODIGO AS CODMATRIZ,
      MATRIZ.NOME AS NOME_MATRIZ,
      FILIAL.NOME AS NOME_FILIAL,
      MATRIZ.CODFILIAL    AS CODFILIAL,
      FILIAL.CODA,FILIAL.CODIGO,FILIAL.CODIGOPAI 
    FROM MATRIZ
    LEFT JOIN FILIAL   ON FILIAL.CODC= MATRIZ.CODIGO
    WHERE MATRIZ.CODIGO                   IS NOT NULL
) TABELAAUX ON TABELAAUX.CODFILIAL = PRODUTO.CODFILIAL
START WITH TABELAAUX.CODA            = PRODUTO.CODIGO 
CONNECT BY NOCYCLE PRIOR TABELAAUX.CODIGOPAI = TABELAAUX.CODIGO;
```

Como deve ficar a estrutura dos dados? Não entendi bem o relacionamento entre as tabelas.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Esse link pode ser uma boa sugestão, mas sua resposta não terá validade se um dia o link deixar de funcionar. Além disso, é importante para a comunidade ter conteúdo aqui no site mesmo. Seria melhor incluir mais detalhes na sua resposta. Um resumo do conteúdo do link já ajudaria bastante! Saiba mais sobre o assunto neste item do nosso FAQ da Comunidade: [Queremos respostas que contenham somente links?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/42/74)

Comment: Ok...sou usuário novo e ainda estou aprendendo como o sistema funciona.

Comment: Tranquilo Samuel, agora sua resposta está bem mais clara